# Banning an ip to visit a particular page

Tags: html, node.js, express, web

I am making a forum for a project. I wish the users to be anonymous to the public but want to store their ip addresses in my database so that I can block them if they pass any derogatory remarks or vulgar content on the forum. Once a user is blacklisted, he/she cannot make a post request to the forum. So they cannot post. What are the possible flaws in this project? And how do I come over this solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking a user by blocking their IP address is not feasible. IP address that users use will change frequently . Even if they don't change, once you block the IP, they will change the IP immediately.

A better way would always be to have users register and then use the account to post anything. But, of course don't show their name or any details in the post. Don't link the user posting the content to any user profile. Only if they post anything which don't meet your posting guideline, just block the user.

You might also need privacy policies and user policies to provide privacy to users, if you are creating that kind of forum.

Comment: Thanks. My requirements are to make the forum work but I have a condition not to register users. Any other possible solution?

Comment: Registering a user doesn't mean they will provide details, just a random username and password. If they can post a content to your forum, they can register with a username and password.                                                                                                                                          Blocking the IP will not work. There doesn't seem to be any other feasible solution.               One way is to check every post posted by someone and remove it. But, of course, you cannot think of blocking a user but you can block a post since you wouldn't even have user.

Answer (score -1):

### How do I block an IP address?

You can add this to your .htaccess

If you don't know what a .htaccess file is, it's a file you put in a folder of your website. It's just called ".htaccess". You can put these files in folders, and they will apply to the files of the folder that they are in, and any sub folders. This will only apply to some servers, so you could ask your web host for more information.

Anyway, pop this into that .htaccess file, and replace "x.x.x.x" with a real IP address:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from x.x.x.x
Deny from y.y.y.y
Deny from z.z.z.z
# repeat these lines as necessary
```

### How well does it work?

How effective this method actually is is hard to define, because ISPs constantly change IP addresses. This is one reason why hosting a website on a home internet connection  can be difficult. Also, if someone's IP address is blocked, they could just use a different internet connection or use a VPN.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess using vpn could still bypass this method. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it is difficult making foolproof plans, isn't it? You would probably need to make an accounts system to do this. Then you could manage everything easier. Or you could set up a system to filter out bad posts, but it would take time to get a foolproof filter. Also, if you found the answer helpful, don't forget to mark as accepted to help other people find answers.